# Python invalid list node cassandra cluster

Tags: python, cassandra

I have 2 dc and 3 node:
DC1: cas01.dc01.net(172.16.3.15) and cas02.dc01.net(172.16.3.16)
DC2: cas01.dc02.net(172.16.9.3) for example.

Run following script:

```
  cluster = Cluster(['cas01.dc01.net', 'cas02.dc01.net', 'cas01.dc02.net'],auth_provider=auth,protocol_version=3, load_balancing_policy=DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(local_dc='DC1'))
session = cluster.connect('test')

print '_dc_live_hosts:'
for k, v in cluster.load_balancing_policy._dc_live_hosts.items():
    print "DC name: %s; Node address: %s" % (k, [node.address for node in v])

print 'Cluster metadata:'
for host in cluster.metadata.all_hosts():
    print 'Datacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s' % (host.datacenter, host.address, host.rack)
```

and receive response:

```
_dc_live_hosts:
DC name: DC1; Node address: ['cas01.dc01.net', 'cas01.dc02.net', 'cas02.dc01.net', '172.16.3.15']
DC name: DC2; Node address: ['172.16.9.3']
Cluster metadata:
Datacenter: None; Host: cas01.dc01.net; Rack: None
Datacenter: None; Host: cas01.dc02.net; Rack: None
Datacenter: DC1; Host: 172.16.3.15; Rack: Rack1
Datacenter: DC2; Host: 172.16.9.3; Rack: Rack1
Datacenter: DC1; Host: cas02.dc01.net; Rack: Rack1
```

Why duplicate nodes? 
If you specify a list of IP address:

```
cluster = Cluster(['172.16.3.15', '172.16.3.16', '172.16.9.3'],auth_provider=auth,protocol_version=3, load_balancing_policy=DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(local_dc='DC1'))
...
```

list of nodes is correct:

```
_dc_live_hosts:
DC name: DС1; Node address: ['172.16.3.16', '172.16.3.15']
DC name: DС2; Node address: ['172.16.9.3']
Cluster metadata:
Datacenter: DС1; Host: 172.16.3.16; Rack: Rack1
Datacenter: DС1; Host: 172.16.3.15; Rack: Rack1
Datacenter: DС2; Host: 172.16.9.3; Rack: Rack1
```

Please help.

Comment: What are your seeds ? What snitch do you use ? You can find the answers in your cassandra.yaml file. If it is a PropertyFileSnitch, can you include the content of your cassandra-topology.properties ?

Comment: Node cas01.dc01.net: - seeds: "cas01.dc01.net,cas02.dc01.net"         Node cas02.dc01.net: - seeds: "cas01.dc01.net,cas01.dc02.net"          Node cas01.dc02.net: - seeds: "cas01.dc02.net,cas01.dc01.net" endpoint_snitch: PropertyFileSnitch
topology:                                                           cas01.dc01.net=DC1:Rack1
cas02.dc01.net=DC1:Rack1
cas01.dc02.net=DC2:Rack1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the only problems but :

- all nodes must have the same seeds
- seeds list must include at least one node of each datacenter

Try this :

```
    - seeds : "172.16.3.16, 172.16.9.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

A short description of how the driver works that will clarify your question:

1. the list of nodes that are passed in to the `Cluster` constructor are the initial contact nodes

   The driver selects one of these to create a control connection. It's a good practice to pass more than 1 node so the driver can attempt different connections if one of the nodes is not accessible immediately.
2. using the control connection established at step 1, the driver retrieves information about the cluster topology from the `system` tables. It uses these details to populate the cluster metadata objects.

   The information in the `system` tables (specifically `peers` table) reflects the configuration of each of your nodes (based on `broadcast_address`, `rpc_address`, etc.)